# RewriteEngine On showing Apache test page

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have centos 7 and I need to put this `.htaccess` file inside one of my directories (`www/html/forum`) in order to display friendly URLs so instead of looking like `example.com/index.php?user=222` it would look like `example.com/user/222`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This worked fine back on my old centos 6.8 but on 7 all it does is to display the Apache test page and all directories and files inside forum show as forbidden. Why is that?

**UPDATE:** `/www/html/forum` is the document root and the site is accessed by a "parked domain" (`example.com`).

Answer (score 1):

> **UPDATE:** The assumptions made here are wrong so this answer is mostly irrelevant now. This answer is just for future reference.

---

We're going to have to make some assumptions to answer this...

- `/www/html` is your document root and therefore `/forum` is a subdirectory, off the document root in which this `.htaccess` file is located.
- All requests should be relative to the `/forum` subdirectory. (Which I assume is why this `.htaccess` file is in the `/forum` subdirectory.)

Try changing your directives to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Note that I've changed the `RewriteBase` directive and made both `RewriteRule` *substitutions* relative (ie. no slash prefix).

> instead of looking like `example.com/index.php?user=222` it would look like `example.com/user/222`.

I'm assuming that everything is in the `/forum` subdirectory, so this would need to be present in both these URLs: `example.com/forum/index.php?user=222` and `example.com/forum/user/222` respectively. You would only be able to remove the `/forum` subdirectory from the URL if this `.htaccess` file was in the document root. (If a request of the form `example.com/index.php?user=222` worked successfully then "something else" is going on here.)

> This worked fine back on my old centos 6.8 but on 7 all it does is to display the Apache test page

I don't really see how this could have worked on your "old centos 6.8", unless you had a different directory structure and this was all in the document root and not a subdirectory?

I can only assume that the "Apache text page" is `index.php` in the document root? Otherwise, where is this located?

Comment: the url is example.com without the forum because the parked domain is pointing to forum so forum is the root directory of that domain. That apache page I dont know where it is.

Comment: Ah OK, that completely changes things. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files along the filesystem path? What do you get if you simply request `example.com/index.php` (`example.com` being your parked domain)? Presumably `/user` is not a physical subdirectory? Are you externally redirected to the "Apache test page"??

Comment: No, I have only that htaccess. example.com/index.php gives me a forbidden page and user is not a subdirectory.

Comment: Curious, `example.com/index.php` gives you a "forbidden page" (403?), but `example.com/index.php?user=222` routes OK? Or is that only when the `.htaccess` directives are temporarily removed? (Although, if you access `example.com/index.php` or `example.com/index.php?user=222` it really shouldn't matter whether this `.htaccess` file exists or not - since those directive won't do anything if you access `/index.php` directly - assuming this is a physical file. ???)

Comment: No, all urls will give me a forbidden page except example.com which shows the apache test page.

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` at the top of your `.htaccess` file. It seems like there is "something else" going on here? From your question on ServerFault you said that it works OK (but with "ugly" URLs) when you remove the `.htaccess` file? Is that correct?

Comment: I tried but it didnt do anything. The test page wont appear if I remove the htaccess file indeed but I need it to display the URLs the way I want.

Comment: Something's a bit funny... there really shouldn't be any difference between `example.com/` and `example.com/index.php`, regardless of whether this `.htaccess` file is present or not? Presumably you don't rely on directory indexes? It might offer a clue if you can find where the "Apache test page" is coming from?

Comment: I guess the page is inside the apache installation directory but I dont know.

Comment: Help please?????