# www on domain shows the Apache Test page but bare domain (and other domain) work fine

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I just finished setting up my server. Something is a little odd though. I have 2 domains (example.net and example.com) pointing to the same directory /var/www/html/forum. They both show right, except for one thing. www.example.net shows the apache test page and all other inner pages give a forbidden error. However, www.example.com works fine just as its counterpart without the WWW. Why is that? Whats wrong with the .net domain?

Comment: This is a common mistake. You have to set up the sites www.example.com and www.example.net too or use the ServerAlias directive within your config files.

Comment: On apache virtual server?

Comment: See my example configurations in this answer. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/virtualhost-config-routing-and-wildcard-usage/83320#83320

Comment: Thank you. Although the weird thing is that I didnt need to do that on my old server and not even on this one for example.com so im somewhat puzzled.

Comment: When a web server gets a request packet, it tries to match the request header to a site. If there is not a match, most simply return the first site. That is what was happening and likely happened before. Cheers!!

Comment: Is this different to your [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/105870/1243)? Your earlier question suggested this was a problem with your `.htaccess` file and you apparently got different behaviour depending on whether the `.htaccess` file was present or not ("_The test page wont appear if I remove the htaccess file_" you said). However, this question appears to suggest a fundamental server config issue that @closetnoc describes. Please add the relevant sections from your server config / virtual hosts to your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have added aliases for both names to your site. If you are using third-party DNS you will have to make sure that is properly set up as well.

Comment: You mean by creating a virtual host on apache web server?

Comment: Michael, welcome to Stack Exchange Pro Webmasters - your answer may be correct, but it isn't particularly useful.  You seem knowledgable, help the OP by describing the steps to add an alias for the site and what they need in DNS.